# Why is my fiddle not behaving correctly?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-architect

My JSON that I want to render as a tree is

```
{
    "productOfferings": [
        {
            "text": "Mobile subscription with Internet access 2GB and iPad 32GB",
            "description": "Joors 2GB mobile broadband and iPad 32GB",
            "productOfferings": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "text": "Ipad with 32 GB storage",
                    "description": "A iPad 32 GB Product Offering",
                    "productSpecification": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "text": "IPad",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "text": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB",
                    "description": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB",
                    "productSpecification": {
                        "id": 9,
                        "text": "Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access",
                        "description": "Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access",
                        "productSpecifications": [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "text": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card",
                                "description": "This is the classic Subscription product of a Mobile Network totally void of Services, so it can only be used for accessing a HPLMN. Simply put a MSISDN + SIM"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "text": "Mobile Internet access",
                                "description": "This is a GPRS Service for a Mobile Network Access Product for accessing Internet"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to render a tree with extJS like it does with my json in jsonviewer.stack.hu

[image]

I tried doing it with a fiddle but it couldn't be done and several things are strange about the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/auBTH/24/

When I make the root invisible, it becomes two roots. Very strange. And the displayField can't be set, it must have the name "text" but I can't change my json just because of extJS. I want the text field to have the name "name". And I've been trying to render the produtSpecification like jsonviewer.stack does but it is incomprehesible how to do it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first hint, ids must be unique within the JSON: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/6795/20131025-xarw-24kb